# how to transfer a sql database file to another computer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ssms

I want to create a database with SQL Server Management Studio 2012 in my pc and want to use it in another computer.I copy it to my friend's pc and attach it in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 but it does not work correctly and my program in visual studio 2012 can not connect to it.we working on a windows form application with visual studio 2012

Answer (score 2):

You can't just copy the .mdf and .ldf files over to another machine. You need to backup the database, copy the backup to the second machine, and then restore the backup there.

Comment: How can I do that?have you any tutorial?

Comment: @mohammadagah searching on Google for how to backup and restore a database will give you better results than anything I could type here.

Comment: @BrianWillis If you stop the sql service then you should be able to copy the mdf/ldf files.

Answer (score 0):

When you transfer a database to another pc you must detach the database in  your computer and attach it in second machine.After it you must change the connection string name in second machine.This link is useful for learning how can change the connection string:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171887.aspx